# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Graphic Design's [sixth moderator election](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/election/6) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: PieBie]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/election/6), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5963331292626944/0).

Comment: Yay! Looking forward to having you on the team! ^_^

Comment: Looking forward to all the new bells and whistles =D

Comment: congrats and good luck!